# Android- Cannot resolve symbol BaseObservable

Tags: android, android-databinding

I am trying to implement data binding example in android and creating a POJO with bindable variables and i am getting this error ! please help. I am following this tutorial
http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidDatabinding/article.html and here is my code

```
import android.databinding.BaseObservable;
import android.databinding.Bindable;

public class TemperatureData extends BaseObservable {
    private String location;
    private String celsius;

    public TemperatureData(String location, String celsius) {
        this.location = location;
        this.celsius = celsius;
    }

    @Bindable
    public String getCelsius() {
        return celsius;
    }

    @Bindable
    public String getLocation() {
        return location;
    }

    public  void setLocation(String location){
        this.location = location;
        notifyPropertyChanged(BR.location);
    }

    public void setCelsius(String celsius) {
        this.celsius = celsius;
        notifyPropertyChanged(BR.celsius);
    }

}
```

Comment: And where is your code? Please post code

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You should add these lines of code to your app level gradle file as written in the [1.2 section](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidDatabinding/article.html#enable-data-binding-in-your-android-application)

```
android {
    ....
    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
}
```

Comment: I dont know why it was not working but i added dataBinding.enabled true

Comment: As ridiculous as it may sound: this is exactly true. Without this param, Android Studio cannot resolve `android.databinding.ObservableField<>`

Answer (score 1):

```
dataBinding {
   enabled = true
}
```

is deprecated with the newer gradle

Instead:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
// if you use kotlin, apply these plugins too
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

android {
    ...

    buildFeatures {
        dataBinding  = true
    }

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem, I went to the build.gradle (Module:App) and added a block name dataBinding. I am listing my build.gradle code.

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {

    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.jadgroup.mvvm"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```